# Filter array with multiple conditions in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I want to create a filter with multiple conditions in Typescript. Let's suposse I have this array:

```
{
    "id": 1513,
    "procedure": {
        "title": "Sample Procedure 1"
    },
    "category": {
        "title": "Press"
    },
    "status": {
        "status": "IN PROCESS"
    },
    "deadline": {
        "deadline": "OUT OF DEADLINE"
    }
},
{
    "id": 1514,
    "procedure": {
        "title": "Sample Procedure 2"
    },
    "category": {
        "title": "Press"
    },
    "status": {
        "status": "SUBMITTED"
    },
    "deadline": {
        "deadline": "WITHIN DEADLINE"
    }
},
```

I want the user can filter this array using multiple options, for example: Filter the procedures with deadline in "WITHIN DEADLINE" and status in "IN PROCESS".

Edit: I require the user-selected conditions to come from the body, and based on these conditions, generate the new filtered array

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the guidelines for [ask] and how to make a [mre].  Could you also [edit] to clarify • what this has to do with typeorm • what you have tried so far • what sort of filtering you're looking for... like JS array `filter()` method? or something typeorm specific? • whether by "and" you mean you should filter so that *both* conditions are met or that *either* condition is met • why the data is redundant like `{status: {status: x}}` instead of just `{status: x}` • the specific output you're looking for • whether that is the full input array or just a snippet

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I require the user-selected conditions to come from the body, and based on these conditions, generate the new filtered array. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const arr = [{
    "id": 1513,
    "procedure": {
        "title": "Sample Procedure 1"
    },
    "category": {
        "title": "Press"
    },
    "status": {
        "status": "IN PROCESS"
    },
    "deadline": {
        "deadline": "OUT OF DEADLINE"
    }
},
{
    "id": 1514,
    "procedure": {
        "title": "Sample Procedure 2"
    },
    "category": {
        "title": "Press"
    },
    "status": {
        "status": "SUBMITTED"
    },
    "deadline": {
        "deadline": "WITHIN DEADLINE"
    }
},
{
    "id": 1515,
    "procedure": {
        "title": "Sample Procedure 3"
    },
    "category": {
        "title": "Press"
    },
    "status": {
        "status": "IN PROCESS"
    },
    "deadline": {
        "deadline": "WITHIN DEADLINE"
    }
},]

const result = arr.filter(item => item.status.status === 'IN PROCESS' 
    && item.deadline.deadline === 'WITHIN DEADLINE')
console.log(result)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    id: 1515,
    procedure: { title: 'Sample Procedure 3' },
    category: { title: 'Press' },
    status: { status: 'IN PROCESS' },
    deadline: { deadline: 'WITHIN DEADLINE' }
  }
]
```

Edit:

For typeorm you can add OR into an existing WHERE expression:

```
createQueryBuilder("entity")
    .where("entity.status = :status", { status: "IN PROCESS" })
    .orWhere("entity.deadline = :deadline", { deadline: "WITHIN DEADLINE" })
```

https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#adding-where-expression

Comment: I think OP asks how you do it with typeorm.

Comment: OP added the typeorm tag, but the question doesn't mention typeorm at all, being instead about filtering an array in TypeScript, so, without more info, this is the right answer

Comment: In Typeorm or in TS but the filter conditions it based in the user conditions. Is that clear?